# How to access the downloads folder directory path

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download

A component of an extension that I've been developing requires the extension to save files and then (at a later time) open those files again.  As far as I know, this can be done as long as the downloads directory is known.  Saving is easy, you just use:

```
chrome.downloads.download({
    url: fileData,
    filename: "/AppGeneratedSubFolder/"+fileName,
    conflictAction:'overwrite',
    saveAs:false
}
```

And I can perform the opening process if I have included the correct permission in the manifest and have the "Allow access to file URLs" box checked by the user.

I can then access the file by using the following:

```
var missing = "userInputRightNow"
var open= "file:///"+missing+"/AppGeneratedSubFolder/"+fileName;
chrome.windows.create({
    url:open,
    type:'popup',
    state: 'maximized',
    focused:true,
});
```

However, this requires me to somehow get the content for the variable labeled missing.  I have done this by directing users to the following page (i.e., opening it in a new window) and telling them to copy the directory into an input box within my application--I then save the value for future use by the application:

```
chrome://settings/?search=Ask%20where%20to%20save%20each%20file%20before%20downloading
```

However, I'm wondering if there is any better approach.  I broadly understand the design decision to not expose a user's file system to extension APIs.  However, I'm wondering if I'm missing some work around:

- Is there another permission that might enable this that I haven't considered?
- I don't actually have any reason to "know" the missing information.  I would be satisfied with a way to reference the relative path without knowing it.
- Or some superior method to obtaining that missing information as trying to walk users through the process of copying and pasting it (no matter how clear) seems to be a major bottle neck in my installation process.

Comment: Why don't you save the `downloadId` and then use `chrome.downloads.open`?

Comment: I believe that this only persists as long as the user keeps their download history in chrome.  Correct me if that is wrong.

Comment: You can download a dummy html URL (e.g. a page inside your extension or a `data:` URI with an empty html string inside) using chrome.downloads API, then use `chrome.downloads.open` and intercept the new tab URL request via chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest, and if it matches `file://` scheme, redirect to the actual URL.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  How would redirecting resolve the fact that i don't know the downloads directory path?